# modifying python script for smooth Gaussian fit

Tags: python

I have this python script:

```
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

x = ar(range(10))
y = ar([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])

n = len(x)
mean = sum(x*y)/n
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[max(y),mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'r-',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
print(sigma)
print(mean)
plt.show()
```

That outputs a very jagged Gaussian fit to the data. How can I improve this to make it nice and smooth - without increasing the raw data points.

Comment: "How can I improve this to make it nice and smooth - without increasing the raw data points. ". That doesn't make sense: if you keep the amount of (x) data points, your figure ends up with the low resolution it has. Remember, the fit to the raw data, and drawing the figure, are two different things. If you do want to show the raw data as well, overplot those on top of a higher resolution curve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use more points to plot the result. Therefore you need to create two more arrays which then contain the points. Maybe something like this:

```
import numpy as np

#Calculation is done here

#Now calculate more points for the plot
step = 0.1
plotx = []
ploty = []

for value in np.arange(min(x),max(x)+step,step):
    plotx.append(value)
    ploty.append(gaus(value,*popt))
```

You need to add `plt.plot(plotx,ploty,'b-',label='more points')` in the plotting section.